# Controlling Multiple Instances of VLC etc. by a "Unified" Hotkey Command

Tags: linux, automation, vlc-media-player, shell-script, hotkeys

I wish to invite suggestions regarding if and how is the following achievable:

controlling multiple instances of a media player (say VLC) by one "unified" hot-key command.
eg. Pressing spacebar would pause/play all instances of VLC
Pressing CTRL+ UP would increase volume in all instances of VLC and likewise for all hotkey commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) for that kind of tasks. AutoHotkey has very strong capability for hotkey management.

*Always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it for your specific use, but I would suggest giving [keybroadcast](https://launchpad.net/keyboardcast) a shot.